# How to generate multidatacenter tokens for murmur3 partitioner

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I had a cassandra ring with 3 nodes, hadoop ring with 3 nodes and solr ring with 3 nodes all are in same cluster.

My plan is to write the data into cassandra ring and using cassandra DC replication I will replicate the data into other two rings( Hadoop and solr)

I used vnodes for the cassandra ring and I need to use tokens for the hadoop and solr because vnodes are not supported for hadoop/solr.

My question is how to generate the multiple datacenter tokens for murmur3 partioner?

Comment: Same question as this. At first, I tried to use the same set of tokens in each DC (e.g. DC1 uses tokens A, B, C; DC2 also uses tokens A, B, C). But it seems that a token must be unique across the whole cluster because when you try to start another node that re-uses the token of an existing node from a different DC, that other node disappears from the ring (both in OpsCenter and nodetool status). I'm using Murmur3Partitioner too

Answer (score 1):

In Multi-DC setup you can chose one DC and calculate tokens evenly for the nodes in one DC. The nodes in other DCs will have the same tokens + some offset so that the tokens will be unique. Cassandra package as a tool to help you calculate the tokens:

https://www.geroba.com/cassandra/cassandra-token-calculator/

Comment: The token-generator tool is for random partitioner. Am using murmur3 partitioner. So, I had 3 nodes in hadoop and 3 nodes in solr. Can I calculate tokens for 6 nodes and distribute between them?

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR;**
Use vnodes, token calculation is done for you.

You'd do it normally but then just add 100 (anything between 100 and 1000 allows you to fail on bootstrapping more than 10 times without worrying about running into issues where the new nodes auto-join on a previous attempt to the tokens in the second DC. (thanks Joaquin!))

E.g. (notice the last 3 figures in each token)

**DC1**

1. -9223372036854775808
2. -3074457345618258603
3. 3074457345618258602

**DC2**

1. -9223372036854775708
2. -3074457345618258503
3. 3074457345618258502

[Old docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens_c.html), but still valid.

Comment: but this one is not for murmur3partitioner token ?/ its for randompartitioner

Comment: Note that -9223372036854775808 is the absolute bottom of the Murmur3 range, so pushing the 3rd-right-digit to 9 makes it an invalid value as you are now -2^63 - 100.